# How can I trigger script on hook with access to stage and region?

Tags: serverless-framework

I run a script on a serverless hook using any of the plugins that allow me to do this:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-scriptable-plugin
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-hooks-plugin
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-scripts

e.g.

```
custom:
  scriptable:
    hooks:
      before:deploy:deploy: node createEnvFileInteractive.js
```

How can I pass in the `stage` and `region` variables to the script?

Answer (score 0):

I would say there is 2 option how to do it (at least what I tried and aware of).

1. pass `stage` and `region` as the environment variable:

```yaml
# serverless.yml
custom:
  scriptable:
    hooks:
      before:deploy:deploy: STAGE=${self:provider.stage} node createEnvFileInteractive.js
```

2. Set a js script as a hook and take benefit of `serverless` object - [please check 4th example](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-scriptable-plugin):

```yaml
# serverless.yml
custom:
  scriptable:
    hooks:
      before:deploy:deploy: createEnvFileInteractive.js
```

```js
// createEnvFileInteractive.js
const stage = serverless.service.provider.stage
const region = serverless.service.provider.region

const customValue = serverless.service.custom.customValue
...

//or
const {stage, region} = serverless.service.provider
```